# Showing clicked product details and quantity to chat window

Tags: laravel, web, chat, e-commerce, pusher

I am working on an e-commerce project on Laravel, I want to show the details of the clicked product along with selected quantities on a real-time chat system developed using the pusher. 
Scenario:
A customer visits the site(B2B E-commerce), clicks on a certain product, selects the quantity, 
Clicks on (Ask Quotation button). Now I want, the chat windows to be opened with the above information

Comment: Hi,  Unfortunately this post seems like too vague of a question.  I would suggest having a more specific question regarding a specific task you are unable to complete or need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Be more precise in your question.
Do you want help with architecture definitions? Or do you already have something built, but with errors?
Don't get me wrong, but your question looks like you want something done.